# How do I call this function from within JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I want to use JQuery in a Javascript program I'm working on but I ran into some issues with scope.  How do I call myfunction2 from myfunction1 in this psuedo-code? (assume that a new MyConstructor object has been created somewhere and that myfunction1() has been called)

```
function MyConstructor(){...}

MyConstructor.prototype.myfunction1 = function(param) {
   $('#some_element').click(function(){
    this.myfunction2('clicked!'); //this doesn't work
  });
}

MyConstructor.prototype.myfunction2 = function(param) {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myfunction2` can be called with `this.myfunction2()` when in any function of `MyConstructor`.

In your case you are trying to call `myfunction2` inside another function that has a different meaning for `this`. To access `myfunction2` you can create a variable for either `this` or `this.myfunction2` that is in closure scope that extends to the function parameter of `click`

```
var self = this; 
$('#some_element').click(function(){
   self.myfunction2('clicked!');
});
```

or

```
var myfunction2 = this.myfunction2; 
$('#some_element').click(function(){
   myfunction2('clicked!');
});
```